# How to replace a image with another one during html5 drag and drop on a occupied div

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm trying to make a javascript web app using HTML5 drag and drop. It is about a game for kids where they need to drag a number (from 1 to 6, they are all images in a div within a container) to a div whom background has a set number of items. So if the div has a background image of 6 candies they need to drag the numer six on it.

I did fine and I get my code to work on dragging and dropping but I want this to happen:

-When a kid drags a number onto a div and then realizes he was wrong, he could just drag the correct number and the previous one would disappear. But with my current code if you try that the new dragging number dissappears and the div remains with the old number.

Here is my code:

```
// JavaScript Document
window.Mover = window.Mover || {};
window.Mover = ( function ( ) {
    "use strict" ;  

    function Mover ( ) {
    }

    Mover.prototype.allowDrop= function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    Mover.prototype.drag = function (e) 
    {

        e.dataTransfer.setData("Text",e.target.id);

    };



    Mover.prototype.drop = function (e) 
    {

            e.preventDefault();
            var data=e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");        
            e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));


    };  

    return Mover ;
                             }( ) ) ;



    var moviendo = new Mover( ) ;
```

Any help would be appreciated, ty!

Answer (score 0):

`appendChild()` doesn't remove the old element; the new one is probably there, but you can't see it. Try something like this before appending the new element:

```
e.target.removeChild(e.target.childNodes[0])
```

Comment: I tried it and it won't let me replace the new element now, the old number stays there and the new one just keeps in its original position. Thanks for looking this up though.

Comment: Well, that was just an example of picking a child node; I don't know what your DOM looks like. Make sure you're actually removing the right child.